# Model is null in controller action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In a MVC view I have this form

```
@model SalesForceWeb.Models.UserViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Configure", "Home")) {
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.EmailAddress)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.user.EmailAddress)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.user.Password)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.SecurityToken)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.user.SecurityToken)
    <p><input type="submit" id="setupSalesforce" value="Save" /></p>
}
```

And in my controller here is my action result method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Configure(Models.SalesforceUserModel model)
{
    model.UserID = new Guid();
    model.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    // snip, save to database

    return View();
}
```

However the parameter model is null/it's fields are null.

Here is the model

```
public class SalesforceUserModel
{

    public int AccountEventID { get; set; }
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Email Address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Security Token")]
    public string SecurityToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

}
```

Am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: Why is there a different Model at the top of the View? Then the one you are expecting to be passed to your HttpPost method?

Answer (score 0):

Your current view code produces HTML markup like below for the inputs

```
<input id="user_EmailAddress" name="user.EmailAddress" type="text" value="">
```

But your HttpPost action method parameter is `SalesforceUserModel` type on which the EmailAddress property is directly there (not deep level). So for model binding to work, you should generate markup like this

```
<input name="EmailAddress" type="text" value="">
```

To do this, you may explicitly specify the name you want for the input element.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(f => f.user.EmailAddress,new {NAME="EmailAddress"})
```

**OR**

You can update your view model to be a flat-lean view model with those properties.